# can't we have alert() before the sendRedirect in jsp file

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

i want to know how to implement a alert before i redirect from one page to other page.

my code : ( sciptlet )

```
  <% 
       if(condition)
        {
            // alert here. before redirecting other page.
            // now redirect here as fallow.
             response.sendRedirect("sem-duration_old.jsp");

           }
   %>
```

i tried this its not working :

```
   <% 
       if(condition)
        {   
    %>
              <script>
              alert(" we are going to some other page" );
            </script> 
    <%               
            response.sendRedirect("semduration_old.jsp");

           }
   %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Remember the separation between client-side and server-side.  The redirect signal (an HTTP 302 response) is sent by your jsp, then received by the browser.  So regardless of what else you've written to the response buffer (html markup, script tag, and alert) your browser is going to immediately request the Location specified in the redirect.  So your jsp's response will resemble the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1    
Location: http://localhost/semduration_old.jsp
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 0
```

One way to accomplish what you want would be to allow the client to "redirect" themselves using javascript:

```
<% 
    if(condition)
    {   
%>
     <script>
          alert(" we are going to some other page" );
          window.location = 'semduration_old.jsp';
     </script> 
<%
       }
%>
```

Comment: can send parameters to ".jsp" in window.location = 'semduration_old.jsp'

Comment: Yes, just use a query string.  `window.location = 'semduration_old.jsp?param1=value1&param2=value2'`

Answer (score 2):

You can also create another jsp page that messages and redirects.

```
<% 
 String msg = request.getParameter("msg");//means you have to send the message as a parameter
 String location = request.getParameter("location");
%>
<script>
      alert("<%= msg %>");//alert the message
      //you can also display the message using a mark up on the page and use setTimeOut()
      window.location = "<%= location %>";//then redirect
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you.

```
<% 
   if(condition)
    { %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         alert('redirecting');
    </script>
        // alert here. before redirecting other page.
        // now redirect here as fallow.
    <%     response.sendRedirect("sem-duration_old.jsp?current_session");

       }
 %>
```

I haven't tried. But this may not be optimal solution. Have you tried [unload](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) function?

Comment: I tried your code, If you comment the redirect code then the alert will work. For using unload you need to use jQuery plugin, Here is sample code. `$( window ).unload(function() {
alert( "Handler for .unload() called." );
});`

Comment: See this [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_unload) example. This works fine in IE, Don't know what happens for firefox and chrome.

Comment: k fine, can u give the link

Comment: I don't get you. Link for what? Already given the link in my comment above yours.